# Fix "access to perform that action" in a shared sheet

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, shared

Simple sheet script lacks permission to be run by a shared user

I have a simple spreadsheet for scoring a quiz. Each quiz team (in separate locations) has their own copy which I have set up in my account and shared with them. The spreadsheet runs a small script when it starts to enable to user to easily sort scores. Works fine for me but the shared user gets "You do not have access to perform that action. Please ask the owner of this item to grant access to you."
Apologies for what's probably a really basic question. I'm a real newby to this stuff and I've tried to make head or tail of what I need to do but have failed completely! 
Any advice welcomed

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Browser.msgBox("Starting scoresheet setup");

// Hide working columns

var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.hideColumns(26, 2);

var menuEntries = [
                  {name: "Sort Scores Hi-Lo", functionName: "HiLo"},
                  {name: "Sort Tables A-Z", functionName: "AZ"}];
ss.addMenu("Sort Scores", menuEntries);
Browser.msgBox("'Sort Scores' now set up in Menu, above");
Browser.msgBox("Scoresheet setup complete"); 
}

function HiLo() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var teams2 = ss.getRange("Z2").getValue()
var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(9, 1,  teams2, 26);        // 
Sort area A9 - X20;

//Browser.msgBox("Scoresheet sorted with highest score at the top");
range.sort({column: 22, ascending: false}); 
// Sort descending by column A
Browser.msgBox("Scoresheet sorted with highest score at the top");
}

function AZ() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var teams2 = ss.getRange("Z2").getValue();
var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(9, 1,  teams2, 26);
// Sort area A9 - X20;

//Browser.msgBox("Table sort");
range.sort({column:1, ascending: true}); 
// Sort descending by column A
Browser.msgBox("Scoresheet sorted into Table order A to Z");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser.[msgBox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String))() requires authorisation.

[Simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) (onOpen) cannot call methods that require authorisation.

Try SpreadsheetApp.getActive().[toast](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg)() instead.

Comment: Sorry to be completely dumb ... what does 'toast' refer to?

Comment: Did you click the link?